# Google crawling Solspace Rating Vote Links

Tags: solspace, google

I have an issue on a site I maintain where we use the Solspace Rating module. We have added up/down vote links on ratings and are triggering the click with a JavaScript event, however Google (and other search engine bots) appear to be crawling the target URLs and as a result generating thousands of up/down votes during the crawl.

We have tried adding rel="nofollow" and removing the URL from the href and placing it inside a custom data attribute instead but still no joy...

Our markup:

```
{exp:rating:rating_vote_stats rating_id="{rating_id}"}
<a href="#" class="vote" rel="nofollow" data-vote-path="{path='reviews/vote'}/{rating_id}/up">Yes</a>
<a href="#" class="vote" rel="nofollow" data-vote-path="{path='reviews/vote'}/{rating_id}/down">No</a>
{/exp:rating:rating_vote_stats}
```

and our JavaScript/jQuery:

```
$(".vote") .click (function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var link = $(this).data("vote-path");
    $.ajax({
        url: link
    });
});
```

Any suggestions as to how we can resolve this issue without requiring log-in to up/down vote?

Comment: Have you tried adding some disallow rules to your robots.txt to prevent indexing of /reviews/vote ?

Comment: Does disallow actually stop Google from hitting the URL though, I think that it perhaps prevents indexing but does not prevent it from actually being crawled.

Comment: @Bluedreamer is correct.  robots.txt prevents it from being crawled. <meta name="robots" content="noindex"> prevents it from being indexed.

Comment: Nope, robots.txt can prevent a URL from being indexed but it won't prevent it from being crawled. That's my issue. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, working this out in the end. I used a relatively simple .htaccess rule to prevent access to the voting URLs by common robots:

```
# Prevent Robots from voting on reviews
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (googlebot|bingbot|Baiduspider) [NC]
RewriteRule ^reviews/course/(.*)/review/vote/(.*)/(.*)$ - [R=403,L]
```

That does it! :)